# How to filter for variables in a column of one df from another df's column with unequal length in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to select for variables in a column of a DF using the variables from a column in another DF with different length.  I am using Dplyer to filter.

```
DF1                                     
|States | Frequency  |     
|:----  |:------:    |
| AL    | 19         |
| TX    | 15         |
| MO    | 2          |
|CA     | 22         |
|NY     | 66         |

DF2                                     
|States | Total  |     
|:----  |:------:|
| AL    | 11     |
| TX    | 12     |
| MO    | 89     |
```

I am using the following code to filter

```
filter(df1,States %in% df2$States)
```

But I am getting this result

```
[1] States          frequency
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

How can I get only the variables I am interested in DF1?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the output of `dput(head(DF1))` and `dput(head(DF2))`? I guess AL in DF1 is actually " AL" (started with a space)

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue of white spaces
Remove them with `trimws`:

```
library(dplyr)

filter(df1, trimws(States) %in% df2$States)

 States Frequency
1     AL        19
2     TX        15
3     MO         2
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is want you want?If so, then it's simply a typo issue.

```
filter(df1,States %in% df2$States)
  States Frequency
1     AL        19
2     TX        15
3     MO         2
```

## Edit

Here is the data I used to generate the result above:

```
df1 <- structure(list(States = c("AL", "TX", "MO", "CA", "NY"), Frequency = c(19, 
15, 2, 22, 66)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df2 <- structure(list(States = c("AL", "TX", "MO"), Frequency = c(11, 
12, 89)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Sorry assuming the states are spelled correctly.

Comment: If there is no typo, then maybe there is some format issue with your data frame. I updated my answer to provide a reproducible examples of `df1` and `df2` that I used to get the results with your code. Please check if these data frames are identical with yours.  More importantly, please show how the expected output look like.